# Image is not display on the datatable using php json

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to display to the image on the data table.but image not displayed i got error on the console **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string** .what i so i attached code below. please anyone help me to fix them. all images are reside on uploads folder.

**Table**

```
<table id="tbl-projects" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0"  width="100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>                    
                </tr>

            </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
get_all();
function get_all() {
    $('#tbl-projects').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    $.ajax({
        url: "view.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#tbl-projects').html(data);

            $('#tbl-projects').dataTable({
                "aaData": data
                ,
                "scrollX": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                            {"sTitle": "Image", "mData": "immage"
                    "render": function (mData , type, row, meta) {

                        return '<img src="uploads/'+ mData +'">';
                    }
                }

            ]
        }
    });
}
```

**view.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "saless";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id,immage from picc order by id DESC ");
$stmt->bind_result($id,$immage);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $output[] = array ("id"=>$id, "immage"=>$immage);
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: This is a simple syntax problem. There are actually several problems. A `[` without a `]`, missing comma after `"mData": "immage"` and probably some more.

Comment: "render": function (mData , type, row, meta) {  what is the error here

Comment: The reported error is not necessarily exactly on the line where the error is reported. It could be on the line before it, in this case there certainly is an error there, or even several lines away. The reported line is only the point where the interpreter cannot continue anymore.

Comment: sorry sir this line render": function (data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {

Comment: A nice way to see syntax errors (there are many ways) is to [use a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uqnw6sLb/). I copied your JS code in there. Everywhere where there's a line underneath the code there's a problem. Hover over it with your cursor and you'll see what the problem is. Correct them one by one until no lines are left.

Comment: i edited the jQuery code sir   "render": function (mData , type, row, meta) {

                        return '<img src="uploads/'+ mData +'">';
                    }

Comment: sir ....................................???